# ReactJs Material Ui Random Issue

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I sometimes face an issue with material-iu framework.

I have a drawer and in the main I export material-component like table.
I just copied those codes, all working but when i refresh page, it sometimes does like in the attached picture. Is it caused by the way it's not loaded yet or performance.

Thanks

[drawers](https://material-ui.com/demos/drawers/)

[tables](https://material-ui.com/demos/tables/)

[image: test]

Comment: Can you provide a codepen where you've reproduced the issue? Hard to say without more info

Comment: https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/master/docs/src/pages/demos/drawers/PersistentDrawerLeft.js    <- the drawer. https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/master/docs/src/pages/demos/cards/RecipeReviewCard.js  <- the card i putted in the main of drawer

Comment: What browser are you using? I used to have this happen to me when I moved to Firefox Quantum

Comment: Josh Wooding, I use Firefox Quantum, how did you resolve it? thx